# SQS receiveMessage stops to work after first message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm new in SQS and nodejs. I want to receive messages while queue isn't empty, but after receiving first message it stops to work. My code reads first message only in starting of server. How can I read messages all time?

```
sqs.receiveMessage({
    QueueUrl: queueUri,
    WaitTimeSeconds: 3,
    MaxNumberOfMessages: 1
 }, function(err, data) {
   // If there are any messages to get
   if (data.Messages) {
      // Get the first message (should be the only one since we said to only get one above)
      var message = data.Messages[0],
          body = JSON.parse(message.Body);
      var bucketName = body.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
      var fullName = body.Records[0].s3.object.key;
      var fileName = Path.basename(fullName);
      var folderName = Path.dirname(fullName);
      var _45px = {
        width: 45,
        dstnKey: fileName,
        destinationPath: "thumbnails"
      };

      removeFromQueue(message);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

That code will read one message and stop. If you want to continue reading messages you need to perform some sort of loop to continue calling `sqs.receiveMessage()`. Of course that can be difficult since it is an asynchronous call. I would look into the [Async library](https://github.com/caolan/async).